# How to call certain kinds of tall shoes that women use to wear?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

Because their strange features, even in my own language I find it difficult to decide by what name to call the shoes shown in the image below.

I'm not looking for a technical term, but for a cute and funny name whose meaning, in the right context, elicits a positeve sense of hilarity.

Some terms to which I thought are *stilts* and * *ballasts*.

*Stilts* and *ballasts* can function as funny words in my language, thus my question is: In the aforementioned sense, do they function in the English language? Or, perhaps, are there more appropriate or even slang terms?

---

[image]

Comment: It can be cross-categorized: It's a "sexy high-heel shoe"; it's a sandal; it's a platform; it's a stilletto; it's an ankle-strap pump. But it doesn't have a [goldfish](http://www.exotichighheels.com/el-601-goldie.html?cmp=googleproducts&kw=el-601-goldie&Color=Clear/Floating%20Fish&Size=6&gclid=CLmrxYLXwbkCFRTxOgod23kAlw).

Comment: @J.R. Those goldfish shoes are fantastic. Thank you for proving to me that the internet has everything.

Comment: @Sql - Actually, I'm pretty sure goldfish shoes predate the internet.

Comment: I'd call them "bloody painful" or "feet killers"! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA How about _ridiculous_ or _ugly_?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Those are *platform* shoes; see [pictures](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1016&bih=604&q=platform+shoes&oq=platform+shoes&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1378.2794.0.3206.2.2.0.0.0.0.218.352.0j1j1.2.0....0...1ac..26.img..1.1.218.vK0kBaLcPvg).  (I don't know of a funny name for them, except that some similar shoes are called *[ho shoes](http://pinterest.com/nuttybynature/shoes-ho-shoes/)* .)

Platform shoes with spikes are sometimes called *[ankle breaker shoes](https://www.google.com/search?q=ankle+breaker+shoes&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=AHQvUrSAJ8LhiALftYDoCQ&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQsAQ&biw=1016&bih=604)* or *ankle breakers*.

If you refer to shoes like those in your picture as *stilts*, yes, that will be perceived as humor.  *[Ballasts](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ballast#Noun)* will not be so perceived, since its usual meaning is as a weight or as a fluorescent light control.

Comment: If my daughter needed money to buy platform shoes I would be pretty pissed if I saw the picture above!  Don't think that is it.

Comment: I rather thought ankle-breakers were just shoes with really high heels—platformed or not. I’d call the ones in Atsuto’s picture ***ankle-breaker platforms*** if anything (or just platform spike heels, as cornbread ninja says).

Comment: I think ankle-breaker platforms is a good politically correct choice.  Stripper shoes would be in the ankle breaker section.  I don't have a daughter but if I did I wouldn't care if she wore ankle-breakers as long as they weren't stripper shoes - which is the picture in the question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, yes, combination terms like *ankle-breaker platforms* or *platform spike heels* will be more precise than just  ankle breakers or platforms or spikes.

Answer (score 16):

The picture the OP gave.  We call those **stripper shoes**.

And you are damn right I have [sources](http://www.sinfulshoes.com/stripper-shoes.aspx).  Put the dollar in my shirt.

And since these particular stripper shoes are black, as suggested by @Janus Bahs Jacquet, **dominatrix shoes** works here too.

[Your grandma wears stripper shoes...](http://www.glamour.com/fashion/blogs/dressed/2013/07/are-stripper-shoes-on-the-red.html)

[Flickr accepts stripper shoes...](http://www.flickr.com/photos/randatola/526326783/)

[My girl wears stripper shoes...](http://destinysrehab.com/2010/07/07/round-2-stripper-shoe-alert-beyonce-out-in-london/)

Comment: You may also hear them referred to as _dominatrix shoes_ (or even occasionally _dom shoes_, though this is more tricky, since there is also a brand of shoes called Dom).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes.  I don't know enough about the dom area to know what differentiates the stripper vs. dom shoe but I know they are close.  I am big on shoes, that's why I will partake in a strip club every once in a while.

Comment: I’m not much of an expert, either, but for simple reasons of practicality and ability to move, the mental image I get form ‘stripper shoes’ is always tacky and impossibly high-heeled shoes, but not necessarily platformed ones. The asker’s photo gives an almost exact replica of what my mind conjures up for ‘dom(inatrix) shoes’, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - That is what the shorter strippers wear these days to appear taller or to make their legs look better/longer.

Comment: +1 for the way in which this answer has been substantiated with references.

Comment: Rye, but are you sure 'stripper shoes' elicits a *positive* sense of hilarity? Don't you think that a woman can feel offended if you tell her she wears 'stripper shoes'?

Comment: @AtsutoNagatomo - it can go either way.  Depends on the girl.  Most girls I know refer to them as that.  A person that is "serious" might get offended - but why would that type of person wear these shoes?  Also if there was no visual, I can think of nothing else to call them.  If you were writing a book and said platform shoes or even ankle breakers, the reader would not think of the shoe in your picture.

Comment: @Atsuto - When it comes to fashion, it's hard to invoke a sense of hilarity without incurring the risk of offending someone. That's why these humorous terms are usually tossed about only among close friends, yet carefully avoided in the workplace or with casual acquaintences. **Know your audience**. I know what a [_wife-beater shirt_](https://www.google.com/search?q=wife+beater+shirt&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&safe=active) is, and so does my wife. She wouldn't mind if I called it that, but my boss might.

Comment: @J.R. I don't immagine, then, what happens if your boss is a woman :)

Comment: I find it hard to find an example of a setting where someone would wear stripper shoes, where it would be impolite to call them that... anyone?

Comment: Also @J.R. has a good example with wife beaters but there is a difference.  You can google stripper shoes and it is an accepted fashion term and websites will have categories for stripper shoes.  A dirty white tank top is referred to as a wife beater but probably won't see that as a classification on a website to sell tank tops.

Comment: @RyeBread - Maybe. Then again, [maybe not](http://www.amazon.com/Quality-A-Shirt-Beater-Ribbed-Premium/dp/B00ESXZDKW/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1378850722&sr=8-6&keywords=mens+wife+beater+tank+tops). I think your point is valid, but [counterexamples can be found](http://yque.com/bepoteandots.html).

Comment: @J.R. I stand corrected.  Is this good or bad for wife beating?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm not much for fashion, but in the circles of actual dominatrices, *dominatrix* is more often abbreviated *domme*, with *dom* referring to male dominants.

Comment: @JonHanna - thank you - now I know how to shorten dominatrix for those times where I just need to get it out quickly.

Comment: Interestingly, when I search for "stripper shoes" on Amazon, you get a bunch of stripper shoes, most of which do not say "stripper shoe" in their product title (Amazon probably uses terms from reviews and also click-throughs from searches).  Amazon is smart about this, huh?  They want to sell stripper shoes but not use the term... which I think ends up validating RyeBread's point.

Comment: '*Stripper shoe*' - more or less polite/offensive than  '*CFM shoe*'? (CFM = Come Fuck Me; I'm lazy, but I swear it can be ref'd)   //  OP's picture is something *I* might think if you said "platform shoes". // @RyeBread, I think the way to shorten this particular dominatrix is to ask her to remove her shoes ...

Comment: I preferred your unedited version. The cocky/quick fire punchline delivery is lost now (but stripper shoes is still excellent).

Answer (score 8):

I would call them platform spike heels.  Traditional platforms have, well, a platform under the ball of the foot as well as the heel, like these:

[image]

Here is an example of spike heel shoes:

[image]

Comment: Where are the spikes on the image posted by the OP?

Answer (score 8):

Well, I'm hesitant to mention this but, in the UK at least, they are commonly known as 'fuck-me' shoes. Seriously. Wikipedia will tell you more!

Comment: That is the only other term that you could use other than stripper shoes that would actually convey the shoe style.  I have heard this used a lot.  I'm not going to downvote the platform shoes, but they are explicitly vague/wrong.

Comment: Instead of pumps, perhaps "pump me" shoes? :)

Comment: Outside the UK, too.  (Commented above before seeing this - we both felt compelled to allude to references ...)

Comment: There's a little more to these shoes than the usual fuck-me aesthetic. Maybe "fuck-me clodhoppers", to suggest the absurd weight?

Answer (score 5):

Peep-Toe Ankle Strap Platform Heels?
[image]

http://prettyplease.us/2012/11/womens-shoes-pump-it-up-different-types-of-high-heels/

Comment: It's so complicated!

Answer (score 2):

These are platform shoes, but with a high heel. They are called platform heels.

Also, they are referred to as platform pumps; however, pump shoes (court shoes in Britain) do not necessarily have high heels, so in this usage it is implied that platform pumps are high heel shoes.

Answer (score 2):

I'd call those [Stilettos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiletto_heel), though in looking up examples, that appears to refer more to just that particular type of heel than to the shoes you've pictured, which have a high, thin heel in combination with a platform front. They're really more of a combination stiletto/platform.

Answer (score 1):

- Ankle-breakers
- Podiatrist's dream
- Booster-feet
- Skyscrapers
- Elevator shoes
- Miss-takes
- Heel-tons

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the dash and extra `s` in _miss-takes_ :).

Comment: I like the "podiatrist's dream".  :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe a funny term would be clod hoppers, or maybe call them a pair of broken ankles?  To call them Peacocking Shoes would also be pretty funny, they're super outrageous to attract attention.

Comment: Where I come from (Yorkshire, UK) 'clodhoppers' refers to big boots or even just big feet. It comes from 'clod' (of turf) being part of a bog: a country person who wears big boots to get around on uneven ground. You would say to a clumsy person "Hey, watch where you're putting your clodhoppers!" - a stereotype of a country person being rough and uncultured and not used to being indoors amongst refined people! Stiletto heels would definitely not be any use in a bog.